# GridView Editing With Mootools

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, gridview, mootools

I've a grid view which has BoundField columns, an Edit link and a Delete link.

For the Edit link, is it possible to call a modal box by MooTools with fields in it?

Note that previous values of the fields are displayed before making an update.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [jquery](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/06/masterdetail_with_the_gridview_1.html) or [ModalPopupExtender](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/04/masterdetail_with_the_gridview.html) AjaxToolKit control?

Still, you can use the jquery tutorial for your mootools implementation. You can get a good idea from it to do it your own.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I was hoping of accomplishing this without using Ajax Control Toolkit.

Comment: If you check the jquery tutorial this would help you to implement the same solution on mootools. A very fine tutorial how they integrate jquery modal window for edit a record. This would be very helpful for something similar on mootools.